# JAVA SQLServerException: The index is out of range

Tags: java, sql-insert, jar, z-index

Bom dia,

Sou novo em JAVA e estou com problemas em fazer manutenção em um sistema legado...
Utilizo a IDE Eclipse e nela o código está Ok, sem críticas.
Estou fazendo a leitura de um formulário num sistema web, pegando alguns campos e inserindo no banco de dados. Esta inserção é em uma tabela onde o sistema nunca gravou (ele já escreve em outras tabelas do banco). Na mesma classe existem outras inserções no banco (funcionando corretamente), então fiz meu trecho de código exatamente como estão os outros.
Este é um exemplo que Funciona:

```
// Insere itens do pedido
                                StringBuilder insertItensPedido = new StringBuilder();
                                insertItensPedido.append(" INSERT INTO INT_SUPD ( ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        EMP_FIL, ESTAB, DEPOSITO, NR_PEDIDO, LINHA_PED, SEQ_REGISTRO, TIPO_MANUT, REG_EXP_IMP, ORIGEM_REG, PROC_ORIGEM, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        C_PROD, FORNEC, NR_COTACAO, NR_REQUIS, LINHA_REQ, OS, STA_REG, PRIORIDADE, DT_PEDIDO, DT_ENTREG, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        DT_ENT_PREV, DT_ENT_ORIG, DT_ULT_ENT, PORC_ICM, VEZES_ENT, LISTA, QT_ENTREG, QTDE, UNIDADE, BASE_UNIT, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        VR_UNIT, PRECO_TOT, PERC_DESC, PERC_IPI, VLR_DESC, VLR_IPI, VR_ENTR, SEQ_ALT, COD_TRIB, TRAT_FISC, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        COD_GEN, CONTA, DG_CONTA, C_CUSTO, DG_CCUSTO, CONTA2, DG_CONTA2, C_CUSTO2, DG_CCUSTO2, GERA_FLUXO, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        LIVRE, BATCH_PROG, BATCH_DATA, BATCH_HORA, ESTAGIO, DT_INIC_EXEC, PERIODO, PROJETO_OBRA, PROJETO_ETAPA, APROVADOR_PROX, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        APROV_AVISADO, DT_APROVACAO, DT_VALIDADE, SOLICITANTE, UNID_FORN, FATOR_UN_FORN, CUSTO_QT_SOLIC, CUSTO_QT_APROV, COND_PAGTO, TIPO_DESPESA, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        LIVRE_1, LIVRE_2, LIVRE_3, LIVRE_4, LIVRE_5, CAMPO_USUA1, CAMPO_USUA2, CAMPO_USUA3, CAMPO_USUA4, CAMPO_USUA5, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        STATUS_REG, MSG_ERRO, OPERADOR, DATA_ALTER, HORA_ALTER, TIME_STAMP");
                                insertItensPedido.append("             ) VALUES ( ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        '31940001', '1', '1', ?, ?, '1', 'INC', 'IMP', 'LECOM', 'REQ COMPRAS', ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        ?, ?, '0', ?, '0', '0', 'L', '0', ?, ?, ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        ?, NULL, NULL, '0.0000', '0', '0', '0.000000', ?, ?, 'U', ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        ?, ?, '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '0', '0', '0', ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        '0', ?, ?, ?, ?, ' ', '0', ' ', '0', '0', ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        '0', ' ', NULL, '0', 'AV', ?, '110', ' ', ' ', ' ', ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        ' ', NULL, NULL, ?, ' ', '0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', ?, '0', ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        '0', '0', '0.000000', ' ', NULL, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                        'N', ' ', ?, ?, '0', '1' ");
                                insertItensPedido.append("                      ) ");

                                int seqLinhas = 1;
                                List<Map<String, Object>> dadosGridItensRC = integracaoVO.getDadosModeloGrid("ITENS_RC");

                                for (Map<String, Object> dadosLinha : dadosGridItensRC) {
                                    // String item = Funcoes.nulo( dadosLinha.get("ITEM").toString(), "");
                                    // String qtd = Funcoes.nulo( dadosLinha.get("QTD").toString(), "");

                                    BigDecimal ItemQtd = new BigDecimal(0);
                                    BigDecimal itemVlrUnit = new BigDecimal(0);
                                    BigDecimal itemVlrTot = new BigDecimal(0);

                                    String auxItemQtd = Funcoes.nulo( dadosLinha.get("ITEM_QTDE").toString(), "").trim();
                                    String auxItemVlrUnit = Funcoes.nulo( dadosLinha.get("VALOR_UNIT").toString(), "").trim();
                                    String auxItemVlrTot = Funcoes.nulo( dadosLinha.get("VALOR_TOT").toString(), "").trim();

                                    if( !"".equals(auxItemQtd) ) {
                                        ItemQtd = new BigDecimal(auxItemQtd);
                                    }

                                    if( !"".equals(auxItemVlrUnit) ) {
                                        auxItemVlrUnit=auxItemVlrUnit.replace(".", "");
                                        auxItemVlrUnit=auxItemVlrUnit.replace(".", "");
                                        auxItemVlrUnit=auxItemVlrUnit.replace(",", ".");
                                        itemVlrUnit = new BigDecimal(auxItemVlrUnit);
                                    }

                                    if( !"".equals(auxItemVlrTot) ) {
                                        auxItemVlrTot=auxItemVlrTot.replace(".", "");
                                        auxItemVlrTot=auxItemVlrTot.replace(".", "");
                                        auxItemVlrTot=auxItemVlrTot.replace(",", ".");
                                        itemVlrTot = new BigDecimal(auxItemVlrTot);
                                    }


                                    try( PreparedStatement pstAux = cnOmega.prepareStatement(insertItensPedido.toString()) ){

                                        logger.info("INSERT INTO INT_SUPD: codPedidoRC=" + codPedidoRC + ", seqLinhas=" + seqLinhas + ", ITEM_COD=" + dadosLinha.get("ITEM_COD").toString().trim() + ", fornCod=" + fornCod + ", dataInsertRC=" + dataInsertRC.format(formatador) + ", ItemQtd=" + ItemQtd.setScale(6).toString() + ", ITEM_UM=" + dadosLinha.get("ITEM_UM").toString().trim() + ", itemVlrUnit=" + itemVlrUnit.setScale(6).toString() + ", itemVlrTot=" + itemVlrTot.setScale(4).toString());

                                        int param = 1;
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, codPedidoRC);                                                             // NR_PEDIDO
                                        pstAux.setInt(param++, seqLinhas);                                                                  // LINHA_PED
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, dadosLinha.get("ITEM_COD").toString().trim());                            // C_PROD
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, fornCod);                                                                 // FORNEC
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, integracaoVO.getCodProcesso());                                           // NR_REQUIS
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, dataInsertRC.format(formatador));                                         // DT_PEDIDO
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, prazoEnt);                                                                // DT_ENTREG
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, prazoEnt);                                                                // DT_ENT_PREV
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, ItemQtd.setScale(6).toString());                                          // QTDE
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, dadosLinha.get("ITEM_UM").toString().trim());                             // UNIDADE
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, itemVlrUnit.setScale(6).toString());                                      // VR_UNIT
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, itemVlrTot.setScale(4).toString());                                       // PRECO_TOT
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, conta);                                                                   // CONTA
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, digitoConta);                                                             // DG_CONTA
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, centroCusto);                                                             // C_CUSTO
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, digitoCentroCusto);                                                       // DG_CCUSTO
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, dataInsertRC.format(formatador));                                         // DT_INIC_EXEC
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, solicitante);                                                             // SOLICITANTE
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, codnPagto);                                                               // COND_PAGTO
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, operador);                                                                // OPERADOR
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, dataInsertRC.format(formatador));                                         // DATA_ALTER

                                        int valor = pstAux.executeUpdate();
                                        logger.info("executeUpdate: " + valor);
                                    }

                                    seqLinhas++;
                                }
```

Aqui está o meu trecho do código (onde ocorre o erro, sempre na linha do primeiro pstAux)

```
// Insere Descrição Alternativa
                            int seqLinhas1 = 1;
                            StringBuilder insertDescAlter = new StringBuilder();

                                for (Map<String, Object> dadosLinha : dadosGridItensRC) {

                                    String auxItemDescAlt = Funcoes.nulo( dadosLinha.get("ITEM_DESC_ALT").toString(), "").trim();
                                    String codItem = Funcoes.nulo( dadosLinha.get("ITEM_COD").toString(), "").trim();

                                    if(!"".equals(auxItemDescAlt)) {

                                    insertItensPedido.append(" INSERT INTO LITE ( ");
                                    insertItensPedido.append("                        EMP_FIL, DATA_SET, ESTAB, DEPOS, C_PROD, C_PROD_COMPON, DESCRICAO, ETAPA, DT_LITE, LINHA_PED, ");
                                    insertItensPedido.append("                        ENTREGA, NUMERO, ORDEM, SEQ, SUB_SEQ, TIPO, ESTAB_C, DEPOS_C, OPERADOR, DATA_ALTER, ");
                                    insertItensPedido.append("                        HORA_ALTER, QTDE, TIME_STAMP ");
                                    insertItensPedido.append("             ) VALUES ( ");
                                    insertItensPedido.append("                        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ");
                                    insertItensPedido.append("                        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ");
                                    insertItensPedido.append("                        ?, ?, ? ");
                                    insertItensPedido.append("                      ) ");
                                    
                                    try( PreparedStatement pstAux = cnOmega.prepareStatement(insertDescAlter.toString()) ){

                                        logger.info("INSERT INTO LITE: codPedidoRC=" + codPedidoRC + ", seqLinhas1=" + seqLinhas1 + ", codItem=" + codItem + ", auxItemDescAlt=" + "Descrição Complementar" + ", OPERADOR=" + operador + ", dataInsertRC=" + dataInsertRC.format(formatador));

                                        int param = 1;
                                        
                                        pstAux.setString(param, "31940001");                                                            //EMP_FIL
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "SUPD");                                                              //DATA_SET
                                        pstAux.setInt(param++, 1);                                                                      //ESTAB
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "1");                                                                 //DEPOS
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, dadosLinha.get("ITEM_COD").toString().trim());                        //C_PROD
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, " ");                                                                 //C_PROD_COMPON
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, dadosLinha.get("ITEM_DESC_ALT").toString().trim());                   //DESCRICAO
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, " ");                                                                 //ETAPA
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "0");                                                                 //DT_LITE
                                        pstAux.setInt(param++, seqLinhas1);                                                             //LINHA_PED
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "0");                                                                 //ENTREGA
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, codPedidoRC);                                                         //NUMERO
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "1");                                                                 //ORDEM 
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "0");                                                                 //SEQ
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "0");                                                                 //SUB_SEQ
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "0");                                                                 //TIPO
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "0");                                                                 //ESTAB_C
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "0");                                                                 //DEPOS_C
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, operador);                                                            //OPERADOR
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "dataInsertRC.format(formatador)");                                   //DATA_ALTER
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "0");                                                                 //HORA_ALTER
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, null );                                                               //QTDE
                                        pstAux.setString(param++, "1");                                                                 //TIME_STAMP
                                        
                                        
                                        System.out.println(pstAux); 
                                        int valor = pstAux.executeUpdate();
                                        logger.info("executeUpdate: " + valor);
                                    }
    
                                }
                                    seqLinhas1++;
                            }
```

Eu alterei recente para passar os parâmetros fixos em pstAux. como uma tentativa, antes estava passando os fixos no insertItensPedido.append, mas não tive êxito em nenhuma das versões.
Troquei também a variável param por números fixos 1, 2, 3... tbm não deu certo.
Veja que o log indica que gravou o primeiro trecho (Legado) com sucesso e deu erro no meu, mas pegou os campos do formulário e montou o insert...
Já testei o insert direto no SQL e funciona, o banco não criticou nenhum dos dados.

```
[default - ] - 2020-08-20 15:14:42,349 INFO  [RCInserePedidoV1] INSERT INTO INT_SUPD: codPedidoRC=300136, seqLinhas=2, ITEM_COD=60020237, fornCod=55707140008, dataInsertRC=2020-08-20 03:14:42, ItemQtd=10.000000, ITEM_UM=UN, itemVlrUnit=50.000000, itemVlrTot=500.0000
[default - ] - 2020-08-20 15:14:42,401 INFO  [RCInserePedidoV1] executeUpdate: 1
[default - ] - 2020-08-20 15:14:42,452 INFO  [RCInserePedidoV1] INSERT INTO LITE: codPedidoRC=300136, seqLinhas1=1, codItem=99020131, auxItemDescAlt=Descrição Complementar, OPERADOR=adm, dataInsertRC=2020-08-20 03:14:42
[default - ] - 2020-08-20 15:14:42,553 ERROR [RCInserePedidoV1] ERROR : 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 0 is out of range.
```

Não consegui pensar em mais alternativas para solucionar, por isso corri aqui, se puderem me indicar ou sugerir uma direção, serei grato.

Comment: O problema que eu estou vendo é que você não está incrementando `param` na primeira chamada. Como você está utilizando pós incremento, a variável só é incrementada depois de ser passado para o método, o que significa que em ambas primeira e segunda chamada do método `setString`, você está passando o mesmo valor.

Comment: Mesmo incrementando o erro ocorre na mesma linha. `int param = 1; pstAux.setString(param++, "31940001"); //EMP_FIL pstAux.setString(param++, "SUPD"); //DATA_SET `

Comment: @ebotarelli não precisa colocar esta variavel inteira "param" e nem incrementá-la basta você colocar o indice do insert que é 1,2,3,4 e assim por diante o que vc esta identificando é o indice do insert que é fixo como falei tem que colocar os números de acordo com a qtde de interrogação ou colunas 1,2,3 etc

Comment: @JacobdeOliveira Obrigado, mas não rolou.. fiz essa tentativa o erro é o mesmo `The index 1 is out of range'

Comment: @ebotarelli Sabe qual é o problema vc esta pegando a variavel errada o certo é a "insertItensPedido" e não a insertDescAlter por isso ele ta dando esse erro ele não encontra esse indice por que a string esta vazia

nessa linha aqui : try( PreparedStatement pstAux = cnOmega.prepareStatement(insertDescAlter.toString()) ){

Comment: @JacobdeOliveira bem observado, era isso mesmo. Resolvido esta parte, agora não sei por que está acusando `The value is not set for the parameter number 24` sendo que só estou passando 23 valores.

Comment: tenta colocar essa instancia aqui dentro do for StringBuilder insertItensPedido= new StringBuilder()

Comment: Deu certo @JacobdeOliveira, o que tive que fazer foi limpar a variável `insertPedido`. Aparentemente a mesma vinha com os dados do insert anterior desta classe, por isso ele entendia que haviam mais registros que os 23 que estavam na minha lista.

Comment: Blz, parabéns é isso mesmo ;-)